# How to use PHPMailer in a hosting server without internet connection?

Tags: cloud, phpmailer

my website is hosted in the cloud, but in the cloud server, there is no internet connection. How I will user PHPMailer without using the internet. I am new in cloud hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You won't. You can't send email without an internet connection, and a cloud server without an internet connection is completely pointless.

I think you may be confused about something fairly major...

Comment: Thank u for your response. But my website is running in a cloud where the internet is not accessible. website is running on a public IP which is mapped with our DNS server. We are using G suit mail service

Comment: If "the internet is not accessible", you're not in a cloud, you're offline. I suggest you ask your cloud provider for support.